# Conditional mean vs MAP vs minimum mean squared error

Tags: probability, statistics

is it possible for the value of the conditional median to equal the value of maximum a posteriori probability while they are not equal to the value of the minimum mean squared error? 
Would someone be able to explain yes or no and a counter example? 
Thank you

Comment: The title says "conditional mean" while the text says "conditional median".  Presumably you intend the median, with mean being the same as "minimum mean square error"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

Where the unknown parameter can only take two values, this is highly likely:

- For example if the posterior distribution is $\mathbb P(\theta=1 \mid X=x) = \frac34$ and  $\mathbb P(\theta=0 \mid X=x)=\frac14$, then the conditional median and mode (MAP if you prefer) are both $1$ while the conditional mean (minimum mean squared error) is $\frac34$

Something similar can be constructed for continuous posterior distributions, but such examples will look more artificial